# Bounty-change the reasons

Tags: support, bounty

I had asked a question 10 months ago and right now I gave bounty on that. The reason for bounty I gave was 'More detail require' But after applying the bounty it shows 'The current answers do not contain enough detail'. It contains enough details but I wanted more. Now how can I change the reason for bounty?

Comment: eh wha... how can it contain enough details if you want more?

Comment: @WillieWong: I wanted to explore more. So I asked for more details. But the previous explanation given was enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you can't.

See [I accidentally selected the wrong bounty reason. How do I fix it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111966/i-accidentally-selected-the-wrong-bounty-reason-how-do-i-fix-it)

In this specific case, seeing that you just put on the bounty now-ish, I've refunded your rep and removed the bounty. You should now re-open the bounty and in addition to selecting the "more details required" reason, also type in a more detailed optional text describing what you are looking for in the bounty.

(Now to the general audience reading this: This is a one-time thing. I can't guarantee that I or any other moderators will be willing to refund bounties for "changing reasons" in the future. So be more careful when you open a bounty. )

Comment: Willie Wong- Thank You :)

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't it, for most practical purposes, be a satisfactory solution simply to leave a comment on the question explaining in your own words what the bounty is for?

Comment: What if there were already plenty of comments?

Comment: @draks: I'm not aware of any maximum number of comments that can be added to a question.

Comment: There isn't any, but the latest comments might get collapsed and then you might miss them...